# how to control fans on a laptop in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, laptop, fan, temperature

I have a portable desktop basically. My laptop is a clevo p7xxtm1 and the software that controls the fans is an exe file that I can only install on Windows. I don't want to use wine to install it because I'm not sure how it would work or if it could damage my system.

Is there anything for Ubuntu that would give me direct control over the system fans? I read about `lm-sensor` and `fancontrol`, but those didn't work for me. I installed `lm-sensor` and `fancontrol` doesn't seem to do anything since it can't detect the fans. I assume because they are not pwm and maybe dc instead, but can't say with certainty unless I open it up and check.

Does anyone know of a software package that will allow for fan control on a laptop through Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into these projects by Tuxedo Computers:

(a). Tuxedo Fan Control: https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-fan-control

(b). The user manual: https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-fan-control/blob/master/docs/user/user_manual.md

(c). For advanced parameters, such as the needed `--novendorcheck` launch argument when running it on a non-Tuxedo laptop: https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-fan-control/blob/master/docs/dev/dev_manual.md